# Cannot call the JSON result in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have an action of the controller that return the result as the JSON result.(I test it ready, It works well with this action).

```
    public JsonResult GetProductsByDepList(int id)
    {
        JsonResult jr = new JsonResult();
        var _product = from a in DataContext.GetProductsByDep(id)
                       select new { ID = a.ID, ProName = a.Name};

        jr.Data = _product.ToList();
        jr.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
        return jr;
    }
```

And this is what I loop it in my view :

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       var urlProduct = '<%: Url.Content("~/") %>' + "Products/GetProductsByDepList";
       $.getJSON(urlProduct, function (dataPro) {
          alert(123);
       });
   });
```

I just test it with alert, but it doesn't alert anything when I load my page.
Could anyone tell me how to use Action of controller in jquery??

Thanks and welcome all your answers.

Comment: Have you tried running fiddler to see what if any response you get from the server? Also your method is expecting an id but you are not providing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use with $.ajax in jquery if your json format like this

`{"rows":[{"id":"1","username":"foo"},{"id":"2","username":"bar"}]}`

```
            $.ajax({
                url: urlProduct,
                type:"GET",
                success:function (data) {
                    $.each(data.rows,function(i,rows){
                      alert(rows.username);//will be show username foo and bar

                    });
                }
            });
```

this is the reference http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

and this is reference to json http://www.json.org/

this is library can use for C# http://sourceforge.net/projects/csjson/

Comment: thanks viyancs, and could you please tell me, how can I loop the data instead of the alert(data)?

Comment: what the structure of json in your server

Comment: Sorry I just a pretty beginner of JSON, and I also don't know what is the structure of it, so how can I know the structure of that?

Comment: ok i give example in my answer the structur of json, you can try like that.:)

Comment: what the response from urlProduct?

Comment: if you using asp and c# in code behind i think you can read this link http://williamsportwebdeveloper.com/cgi/wp/?p=494, there are how to make web service with json data in asp and c#.

Comment: urlProduct is response to list down all the products that have the id, equal the id that we pass to the action.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8950/discussion-between-socheata-and-viyancs)