# to get the values from php to jquery using JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am very new to these things .. It might be the easiet question but sitll.....I have to get the date from my mysql database using php and from there to jquery file using JSON to make it work with my jquery plugin. I have put the values in array and used `

```
    $tDate['year']= 2012
    $tDate['month']=03
    $tDate['day']=06


echo json_encode($tDate);
```

`
 and in my jquery I need to read all these data how do I do it .. have been looking into quite a few websites but have no idea

Comment: i think you can refer to this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730788/cannot-call-the-json-result-in-jquery/9730848#9730848
and this is if you use cross domain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`$.getjSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), if the requirement is only to get the json data.

```
$.getJSON('your.php', function(data) {

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    alert(val);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your javascript:

```
$.get('/uri/to/script.php', function(data) {
   console.log(data);
}, 'json');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get('/path/to/your_php_file.php', function(data){
    parseInt(data.year, 10);  // => 2012
    parseInt(data.month, 10); // => 3
    parseInt(data.day, 10);   // => 6 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try the getJson method of Jquery [$.getJson()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

syntaxk would be like this

```
jQuery.getJSON( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] )
```

Eg:

```
$.getJSON('Url of PHP', function(response) {

  $.each(resopnse, function(key, val) {
//do some thing with Val
  });

});
```