# update the div display after jquery post without reloading the page in mvc3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

What is the bestHi everyone, a MVC3 newbie here! please take a look at these:

in my View page, i have there:

```
    <div id = "AccounStatusDiv" class="display-field">
     @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.AccountStatus)
     <input id="btnBool" type="button" class="btnGrid ActStatBtn" value="@(Model.AccountStatus ? "Deactivate" : "Activate")" onclick="ChangeStatus()"/>
    </div>
```

and a script:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
       function ChangeStatus() {
         $.post('@Url.Action("SetAccountStatus", "User")',
              { UserName: "@(Model.UserName)",
                accountStatus: "@(Model.AccountStatus)" });

         // change the display of the AccounStatusDiv elements, or maybe just reload the div element if possible. is it?
       }
     </script>
```

while in my Display Template, i have there:

```
     <div id = "AccountStatusDiv" style="display:inline-block;">
       <img src="@Html.Custom().ResolveImage((bool)Model ? imgPositive : imgNegative)" alt="@Model" />
       <label> @ResourceManager.Localize(resource, display)</label>
      </div>
```

in the controller:

```
      public ActionResult SetAccountStatus(string userName, bool accountStatus)
      {
         SecurityManager.GetMembershipProvider().SetStatus(userName, !accountStatus);
         return AjaxResult.JsonRedirect("/User/ViewUser?username=" + userName);
      }
```

The results are shown only after I reload the page.
I want to display the updated `img`, `label` and `btnBool` elements right after clicking the `btnBool` without reloading the whole page. What is the best way in such case?
Please post your code suggestions, it would be a great help for me!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You're only using `$.post()` to send data (request) to the server. AJAX can be two-fold: send a request, and receive the corresponding response. In your code, you're not receiving data back (or, at least, making the necessary arrangements so that you are).

If the `SetAccountStatus` action of your `UserController` is set to return some data back (maybe through `return Json()`, or similar), you can modify the `$.post()` call to receive it, and have your Javascript react accordingly using a callback function.

```
var data = {
    UserName: "@Model.UserName",
    accountStatus: "@Model.AccountStatus" 
};

var call = $.post(
    '@Url.Action("SetAccountStatus", "User")',
    data
);

// set the success callback here
call.success(function (m) {

    // the [m] variable contains the data returned by the server
    // during the resolution of your call

    // this will be called when your AJAX call succeeds,
    // and you can use this opportunity to update the HTML DOM with new data

});
```

Comment: Can you give me the exact code for that ca.success function? Please see my updated post. I've included there the `SetAccountStatus` action.

Comment: In your action, you're explicitly telling the server to perform a redirect somewhat. Why would you do that if you want the client page *not to reload*?

Comment: Then how can I make this action _not to reload_ ? I'm just tasked to "edit" the web application that's already been coded. And I don't know what these exaclty do.

Answer (score 1):

this is to event click in button and without refresh page

```
$("#btnBool").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
//to do your code, you can use `$.ajax` to request and get response from server
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("SetAccountStatus", "User")',
    type:"GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { UserName: "@(Model.UserName)",accountStatus: "@(Model.AccountStatus)" },
    async:'true',
    success:function (data) {
     alert(data);
     //success   to parsing json if you data type of your response is json
    }
   }); 
}
```

you can use web service to send request and get response from server , and to request,get response from server you can use `$.ajax()` in jquery http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: you can see this demo http://jsfiddle.net/viyancs/qThnX/5/ i'm implemente with `JSONP`

Comment: url in my demo is web service and i'm parse that data with `$.ajax()` and you can see that is not refresh or loading page if you click button the data will be show. this technology is client-server communcation

Comment: what is type of data on your response in server? or you can post in here what is the reponse?

Comment: please see my updated question, I've included there the `SetAccountStatus` action.

Comment: hey i think you can refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730788/cannot-call-the-json-result-in-jquery/9730848#9730848